# Big O Notation With Separated Procedures

Tags: algorithm

Today marks the first day I begin to study Algorithms and Algorithm Analysis. More specifically asymptotic analysis. But before I dive in I have one simple question that needs clarification that I cant seem to find anywhere else. Given the code snippet below what would the algorithm complexity be in Big O notation?

```
// Linear Computation: O(n)
    ....

//Merge Sort: O(n log(n))
    ....

//Merge Sort: O(n log(n))
    ....

//Nested for loops iterating n times each: O(n^2)
    ....
```

My assumption would be Big O: O(n) + (2 * O(n log (n) )) + O(n^2) but by definition of Big O do we simplify this further? Would we just call this program O(n^2) considering it is the worse of the three and can be upper bounded by a constant c * n^2?

Comment: All I see is comments, not code. Do you mean if you combine the n, two nlogn, and n^2?

Comment: Sorry my intentions may not have been clear. The dots are to represent the call to these functions such as MergeSort(myArray). These things are happening one after another but are not nested. All these operations are happening in the same program but one after another synchronously. If I am understanding your question correctly, yes, I mean when combining these operations together but having nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when calculating time complexities, large value of input is kept in mind. Say like n value is 1000000.

When you say,

`Big O: O(n) + (2 * O(n log (n) )) + O(n^2)`,
for this large n, 'n'  and `(2 * O(n log (n) ))` will not grow as much as `O(n^2)`.

So the O(n^2) is the complexity decider for large n, and thatswhy overall complexity given is O(n^2)

Comment: Thank you for you're answer! This helped me more then you can imagine as I finished writing an algorithm to solve a problem I have been working on for sometime now. I can now confirm that my algorithm runs in the complexity that it is required to run in! Note this algo that I am referring to has nothing to do with the question here.

Answer (score 2):

When calculating time complexities, we compute it in terms of BIG-O. Now as our programs are huge it is not possible to compute the total of all complexities and on the other hand, there is no sense of doing it because in any expression consisting of big and small terms, if we change big terms then there will significant change in value but if we change small-term then there is no significant change. For eg take value  10000021   if we change leading one to 2, now our value will be 20000021 (huge change), now change ending 1 to 2, now our value will be 10000022 (little change).  Similarly, when the program contains n^2  it is considered instead of o(n) or O(logn) . Change in n^2 is not considered. Therefore we consider n^2.

Order -- n! , 2^n , n^R ..... , n^3 , n^2 , nlogn , n , logn

Consider the maximum which is present in the program.

Answer (score 1):

For given `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, you can find `C` such that

```
C1 n + C2 n log(n) + C3 n² <= C n²
```

Comment: So would this mean that my assumption would be correct? I could say this program is O(n^2)?

Answer (score 1):

The n^2 term dominates, so the big-O is going to be that. The fact that there's two nlogn terms doesn't change anything, since there's a fixed number of them. And when n is big, n^2 is bigger than nlogn.